# Confusion regarding OpenGL coordinate systems

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, hierarchy, transformation

I'm having trouble understanding the core concept of spaces in OpenGL. I've been reading an online book on modern 3D graphics for a couple weeks now and i often find myself confused with all of the spaces used in a program. To be specific, spaces such as: Model space , World space, Camera space, Clip space. I can't seem to wrap my mind around the order that i should be transforming the matrix from and into, an example from one of my tutorial programs:

```
//.vert shader of a program
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 cameraToClipMatrix;
uniform mat4 worldToCameraMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelToWorldMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 temp = modelToWorldMatrix * position;
    temp = worldToCameraMatrix * temp;
    gl_Position = cameraToClipMatrix * temp;
}
```

cameraToClip , worldToCamera, XtoY, ZtoQ, how can i get an understanding of these spaces in OpenGL, websites? videos? references? Or should i just go back and re-read the information on these spaces in the tutorial until it attatches to my brain.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know how to explain it any better than I did. Especially when the matrices are named about as clearly as they can be.

Think of a matrix like a function. A function has inputs and it returns a value. You must pass the correct input or your compiler will complain.

Consider these functions:

```
Float intToFloat(Int i);
Double floatToDouble(Float f);
Real doubleToReal(Double d);
```

Where `Int`, `Float`, `Double`, and `Real` are user-defined C++ types.

Let's say I need to write this function:

```
Real intToReal(Int i);
```

So all I have is an `Int`. Of the above functions, there is *exactly one* function I can call: `intToFloat`. The name says it all: it takes an int and turns it into a float. Therefore, given an `Int`, the *only* thing I can do with it is call `intToFloat`.

```
Int i = ...;
Float f = intToFloat(i);
```

Well, now I have a `Float`. There is again only one function I can call: `floatToDouble`.

```
Double d = floatToDouble(d);
```

And with that, I can only call `doubleToReal`. Which means our `intToReal` function is:

```
Real intToReal(Int i)
{
  Int i = ...;
  Float f = intToFloat(i);
  Double d = floatToDouble(d);
  return doubleToReal(d);
}
```

Just like the matrix example.

The most important thing that a Vertex Shader does is transform positions from their original space (called model space) to the space that OpenGL defines called clip space. That's job #1 for most vertex shaders.

The matrices are just like those functions, converting the position into intermediate spaces along the way.

Answer (score 0):

There can be no answer to this question until after it is solved.  What will teach well enough to some people, for them to grok concepts, will not do the same for everybody.  My best advice is to learn to be a 3D modeler before you become a 3D programmer.  That's what I did.  Once you have good familiarity with visualization of the data, then you can form mental models more easily, and code with them in mind.  And when you need further visualizations to help you create algorithms, you'll be able to create them without using code.